# Server-side Outlook Out of Office Message only To a contacts group or not to a different group

Tags: exchange, outlook, contacts

I would like Outlook Exchange *out of office* (OOF) automatic replies:

- **Not** sent to semi-spam external e-mails. (I can put these in a local group if that will help; I cannot put them in a system-wide distribution list.)  I have these emails as contacts because I want to process them differently in the client.
- **To go** to some people outside of the Exchange view of my Organization. (see above about dist lists)
- Rules to **run as server-side rules** or code.  That way the OOF replies are sent when I am not connected with a client (as is usually the case when I am running OOF).
- I do **not** have administrative rights to the exchange server.

The default choices in Outlook 2010 are: date ranges, just my organisation, or my organisation and/or Contacts.

It seems that a group that will either designate those who should get the OOF messages would be easiest **IFF** Exchange has access to the group as part of it decision making mechanism.

If you mark this question as a duplicate, please point to the duplicate.  Many people already do this; I thank you. I have listed a few *potentially* related questions (none of them answer this question):

- http://serverfault.com/questions/298220/exchange-2010-auto-responders  Concerns email loops and an automated response to a group mailbox.
- [How do I stop Outlook Out-Of-Office from replying to certain addresses?](http://superuser.com/questions/108097/how-do-i-stop-outlook-out-of-office-from-replying-to-certain-addresses) - this suggests some elimination code, but the  *"Only items that do not match these conditions"* restriction means that I have to list all possible spammers, etc.
- [Exchange 2010, Send automatic response even if outlook or session is closed](https://serverfault.com/questions/825592/exchange-2010-send-automatic-response-even-if-outlook-or-session-is-closed) - is mostly server-based, server-administered options
- [Will Outlook out-of-office reply go to mailing lists?](http://superuser.com/questions/481645/will-outlook-out-of-office-reply-go-to-mailing-lists) this one relies on  headers like `Auto-submitted: auto-generated` or `Precedence: bulk`
- [Exchange 2007 Auto-Reply](https://serverfault.com/questions/265579/exchange-2007-auto-reply) no answer
- The 2012 [Change Outlook "reply to" based upon sent address?](https://serverfault.com/questions/375382/change-outlook-reply-to-based-upon-sent-address) talks about a transport agent and the popular topic of shared mailboxes.  I did not find it applicable.

Maybe this question is: (How do I create an) **Outlook server-side rule using a personal contact group**(?)

Edit:
[Here is the list of actions that shows up in my rule-maker.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBAyH.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done. Server rules can't access your personal groups. The closest you can get is manually adding everyone you want to receive the message to the rule.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer.  I can setup an exhaustive list to reply.  I updated the question with an image of the actions that can be associated.  I don't think that any of these will do the _each one only gets one answer_ type of action that OOL does.  I do not think that you implied that that was the case, I just tag this to see if I have missed something.

Comment: You are correct. There is no rules equivalent of "each one only gets one answer".